# Bridging LAN and wireless using netplan

Tags: 20.04, wireless, netplan, network-bridge

I want to extend my network trough wifi to ethernet connected device. I have PC with Ubuntu 20.04 connected to PC2.

This is my setup:

```
 --------       ------                    ------         ------
 |Router|  <--> | AP |  <~~~~> WIFI <~~~> | PC |  <---> | PC2 |
 --------       ------                    ------         ------
```

I created netplan config

- Connect to wifi
- Bridge wifi and 2 eth ports.

netplan config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:      #for debugging purposes only
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
    enp6s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
    enp7s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
    switchport:
      match:
        name: wlp2s0
      mtu: 1280

  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      access-points:
       "WIFI SSID":
         password: "super_secret_wifi_password"

  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      mtu: 1280
      interfaces:
        - switchport
        - enp6s0
        - enp7s0
      parameters:
        stp: true
```

IP address is not assigned to bridge (br0). But if I delete the bridge and enable DHCP on wlp2s0, interface(wlp2s0) gets address.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Update 1:

bridge-utils is already installed.

brctl show br0

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0         8000.0001297d6efa            yes             enp6s0
                                                         enp7s0
```

brctl addif br0 wlp2s0:

```
can't add wlp2s0 to bridge br0: Operation not supported
```

brctl addif br0 switchport

```
interface switchport does not exist!
```

'''

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Please install `bridge-utils` (if not already installed) and add the output of the following commands to your question: 
`brctl show br0`, `brctl addif br0 wlp2s0`, `brctl addif br0 switchport`

Comment: HI @dummyuser. Thanks for trying to help =) 

I added command outputs in original post under "update 1"

Comment: Looks as expected. Your `wlp2s0` interface is not part of the bridge `br0`. That’s why the bridge does not get an IP address via DHCP from wlan. Even adding the `wlp2s0` manually fails. There are some articles on the internet indicating that bridging with wlan interfaces is not allowed. Your workaround with the switchport interface does not work too. So we know the reason, but we do not have a solution.

Comment: maybe this snippet can help:
https://gist.github.com/Jiab77/76000284f8200da5019a232854421564

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what has gone wrong here, but you cannot "add" your WiFi interface to an ethernet device using `match`.  You should be listing `wlp2s0` directly as a bridge member, not trying to use a `switchport` as an indirection.

Comment: Also, nothing in your config should configure an address on wlp2s0!  You may have some other network config on the system that's conflicting with netplan